# Método list para jComboBox voltando nulo

Tags: java, lista

Olá! Estou com problemas para listar dados do meu BD numa jComboBox. O método que eu uso é o seguinte:

```
public void setComboBoxSetorChamado(List<Setor>setores){
    idSetor = new int[setores.size()+1];
    int i = 0;
    //jComboBoxSetorChamado.addItem("");
    idSetor[i] = 0;
    do{
        i++;
        setor = setores.remove(0);
        jComboBoxSetorChamado.addItem(setor.getNome());
        idSetor[i] = setor.getId();
    }while(!setores.isEmpty());
}
```

Eu já o tinha usado em outras classes e funcionou perfeitamente, mas na classe em questão retorna o seguinte erro:

```
    fev 10, 2015 10:58:27 AM syschamados.view.chamado.ChamadoFormView <init>
    GRAVE: null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at syschamados.view.chamado.ChamadoFormView.setComboBoxUbsChamado(ChamadoFormView.java:66)
at syschamados.view.chamado.ChamadoFormView.<init>(ChamadoFormView.java:44)
at syschamados.view.chamado.ChamadoView.jButtonNovoChamadoActionPerformed(ChamadoView.java:148)
at syschamados.view.chamado.ChamadoView.access$000(ChamadoView.java:21)
at syschamados.view.chamado.ChamadoView$1.actionPerformed(ChamadoView.java:58)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

A linha que está o erro já está destacada. O que posso fazer nesse caso?

Comment: Já está destacada? Mas não há nem o método que o console aponta...

Comment: O método que deveria ser mostrado é `setComboBoxUbsChamado()` e se possivel, marque a linha 66 com comentários, não simbolos `>`, pois afeta o conteudo do texto final.

Comment: @GustavoCinque no caso do `setComboBoxUbsChamado()` no console é de um teste que eu tinha feito anteriormente, mas a função que ele executa é praticamente a mesma do `setComboBoxSetorChamado()` que está no código, mudando somente as entidades.

Comment: Hm... okay, se for assim. No caso, ele não deve estar encontrando a instancia do `ComboBox`, tentou dar um `new JComboBox`, ou qlqr entidade que ela seja, antes de utilizar seus métodos?

Comment: Tentei isso agora e os erros do console não apareceram mais, mas o que eu preciso (listagem da entidade) não funcionou. Fiz dois testes: um antes do `do while` (`System.out.println("teste cbox1: "+jComboBoxSetorChamado.getSelectedItem());`) e outro durante (`System.out.println("teste cbox2: "+jComboBoxSetorChamado.getItemAt(1));`). Os dois retornaram resultados, e mesmo assim o `jComboBox` no form não mostra nada.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta criar uma lista de `Strings` com os valores que você deseja e daí adiciona no construtor do `JComboBox`? Veja exemplo abaixo:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Selecione");
    for (Setor setor : setores) {
        list.add(setor.getNome());
    }
    setorCB = new JComboBox(list.toArray());
```

Para continuar acessando os valores que você deseja, pode continuar com a lista de setores e utilizar um `get(position)`.

Comment: Não tem que inicializar esse ArrayList? Coloquei dessa forma no construtor e não deu certo (mas também não dá nenhum erro no console).

Answer (score 0):

o problema já foi resolvido. Estava na declaração dos componentes do form:

```
public ChamadoFormView(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    //initComponents();
    UbsController ubsController = new UbsController();
    SetorController setorController = new SetorController();
    TecnicoController tecnicoController = new TecnicoController();
    try{
        setComboBoxUbsChamado(ubsController.list());
        setComboBoxTecnicoChamado(tecnicoController.list());
        setComboBoxSetorChamado(setorController.list());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Logger.getLogger(ChamadoView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

No caso, o `initComponents()` estava depois do `try`, e era isso que causava o `null` do `jComboBox` Agora está funcionando sem problemas.